# How would I use FileUploader plugin of DroidGap?

Tags: android, plugins, cordova

I'm pretty new on phoneGap android development.
I have only the basic knowledge in phoneGap android development, so I have some inconvenience
with plugin working.

How could I use [PhoneGap android fileuploader plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/FileUploader) in index.html?

I have read the readme file of that plugin but I could not understood , how would I use it on index.html.

Thanks